# What is the way to print large decimal numbers with separation between decimals?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is enough literature about how to print numbers with points or commas as thousands separators or decimals.

```
1000000.001
1,000,000.001
1.000.000,001
1 000 000.001
1 000 000,001
```

But, what is the pythonic way to print large decimal numbers with separation between decimals? e.g.:

```
0.000 000 001
0,000 000 001
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix